# CountDownTImer With Circular Progressbar in Android

Tags: android, timer, progress-bar, countdowntimer

I want to make Circular ProgressBar with CountDownTimer and also show the time left in minute and seconds at the middle of the Circular ProgressBar.

How can I do something like this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few libraries the best in my opinion is [CircularProgress](https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress)